# R: Conditional replacement using two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe `df`like this:

```
df <- data.frame(fruits = c("apple", "orange", "pineapple", "banana", "grape"))
df_rep <- data.frame(eng = c("apple", "orange", "grape"), 
                     esp = c("manzana", "naranja", "uva"))
>df
   fruits
    apple
   orange
pineapple
   banana
    grape

>df_rep
   eng        esp
 apple    manzana
orange    naranja
 grape        uva
```

I want to replace the value in the fruits column of `df` referring to `df_rep`. If the values in the fruits column of `df` appears in eng column of `df_rep`, I want to replace them with the values in esp column of `df_rep`. So the result should look like this:

```
>df
   fruits
  manzana
  naranja
pineapple
   banana
      uva
```

Point: I don't want to use `ifelse` as in my real data frame there are more than 100 replacement list. The example here is simplified for easy understanding. Nor for loop as my data frame contains more than 40,000 rows. I am looking for a simple and only one action solution.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `merge` function (to simulate a SQL left join) and then the `ifelse` function to replace the fruits with non-NA esp values:

```
df2 <- merge(df, df_rep, by.x = 'fruits', by.y = 'eng', all.x = TRUE)

df2$fruits <- ifelse(is.na(df2$esp), df2$fruits, df2$esp)

#      fruits     esp
# 1   manzana manzana
# 2    banana    <NA>
# 3       uva     uva
# 4   naranja naranja
# 5 pineapple    <NA>
```

#### Data

It's important to set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating the data:

```
df <- data.frame(fruits = c("apple", "orange", "pineapple", "banana", "grape"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df_rep <- data.frame(eng = c("apple", "orange", "grape"), 
                     esp = c("manzana", "naranja", "uva"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `coalesce` from `dplyr` to replace the `NA`s that result from `match` with the respective values from `df$fruits`.

```
library(dplyr)
df$fruits2 <- coalesce(df_rep$esp[match(df$fruits, df_rep$eng)], df$fruits)
df
#     fruits   fruits2
#1     apple   manzana
#2    orange   naranja
#3 pineapple pineapple
#4    banana    banana
#5     grape       uva
```